# Is iso-8859-1 supported in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, encoding, iso-8859-1

this is a simple question: does Silverlight (3.0?) support this kind of encoding?

`Encoding c = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");`

Calling this function in Silverlight 3.0 generate the following error.

`'ISO-8859-1' is not a supported encoding name.
Parameter name: name`

My idea is to parse some file client side and then upload only those part needed for my application. I know that I could upload the whole file and parse it server side but right now could be better having the feature client side (for my needs).

I'll wait for an answer. I have found some  information around but no one explictly said that isn't / is supported.

[Microsoft MSDN - Text Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)

[Microsoft MSDN - GetEncoding method reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencoding.aspx)

Thanks

Giorgio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Silverlight-specific [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c%28VS.95%29.aspx) for `Encoding.GetEncoding` gives the list of supported encodings. Only UTF-8, UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE are supported

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have found (unfortunately) myself that Silverlight was missing this support. I had moved the parsing part into the server. I hope they will insert support soon but for now thanks :)